# Lazy right management for package installation

Tags: apt, package-management, sudo

You can install a package (here `package`), by running

```
sudo apt-get install package
```

Some installation scripts written in bash perform such actions and require the user to enter the password every time. This is in many cases not necessary since the packages were already installed.

Is there a way to look whether the (list of) packages are already installed and only if not ask for additional rights? A one-liner would be nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes oneliner:

```
   dpkg -l | grep packagename | wc -l
```

If it results in zero, this package is not installed.